# How to fetch the values from MySQL with switch case in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, switch-statement

I'm working with PHP and MySQL on a student registration project.

There is a table named `programme` from which I have to find the  value of total no. of registration in every campus.

There are 4 campuses (Delhi, Noida, Jaipur and Mumbai) and 27 courses with 2 date of exam cycle (12-04-2014 and 07-06-2014).

I have to display total no. of registration in every campus for every course in every campus. for e.g. Delhi campus I made this query for first date:

```
$sql="select * from programme where campus1='delhi' && course1='Fashion Design (FD)' && examdate='12-04-2014'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $delhi=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

and it does echoe the result into the `td` for the first cycle.

But now I have to make a single query for 27 courses.

I've thought to do this via `switch` cases, but am unable to do it. How should I proceed?

Here is the Table format which I have to fill from database; it's for one course and similarly there are 26 other courses:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th colspan="10">Course Wise Registration Report</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>PROGRAMME</th>
    <th colspan="2">Delhi</th>
    <th colspan="2">Noida</th>
    <th colspan="2">Jaipur</th>
    <th colspan="2">Mumbai</th>
    <th colspan="2">Cycle</th>
    <th>TOTAL</th>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Cycle-1</td>
    <td>Cycle-2</td>
    <td>Cycle-1</td>
    <td>Cycle-2</td>
    <td>Cycle-1</td>
    <td>Cycle-2</td>
    <td>Cycle-1</td>
    <td>Cycle-2</td>
    <td>Cycle-1</td>
    <td>Cycle-2</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>UG-FD</td>
    <td><?php echo $delhi; ?></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>UG-CD</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>UG-TD</td>
    ------------
  </tr>
```

UG-JD
        ------------

```
    <th>Total</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is DB table structure:

```
examdate campus1 course1 campus2 course2
```

Here is the format which i want :
[image]

Here is the screenshot of DB table programme:
[image]

Comment: mhh it seems a simple question but your question is confusing. Can you edit the question to be more clear?

Comment: @BlueBird : i have edited my question please help me dear

Comment: please post your table structure.

Comment: @BlueBird : i have edited my question please chek it for table structure.

Comment: he means MySQL table structure

Comment: Here is DB table structure:

    examdate campus1 course1 campus2 course2

Comment: Please read about `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`. You just need one query.

Comment: @Jakub Kania: exactly i'm looking for that query

Comment: examdate='12-04-2014'? I really cannot be bothered with this.

Comment: @Strawberry : there are 2 exam date as cycle1 and cycle2.cycle1 having 12-04-2014 and cycle2 having 07-06-2014.so now i have to get the total number of student registered for cycle1 and cycle2 in all 4 campuses for 26 courses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a query something below.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM programme 
WHERE campus1 = 'delhi' AND examdate = '12-04-2014'
GROUP BY course1
```

Listen! this is not the final solution. Your tables structures seems not well organized. It should go through several normalization process. Until I have your complete set of table structure I can not give you a final answer.

For now.. just copy and run the above query in your PhpMyAdmin and see what it produce, then you will get an idea.

**NOTE :** I think it is not possible for you to explain well enough, if so, put some screenshots of your all tables grabbed form PhpMyAdmin and screenshot of your final result how it should looks like.

Comment: after running this query it gives
COUNT(*)
2
10
7
73
8
11
12
9
5
7
6
3
4
3
2
8
1
3

Comment: this count is for each course. If you need to see the names of course also, then add course1 in the select statement. Then you can see count relevant to each course. 'select course1, count(*) from .. ' and so on.

Comment: thanks a ton dear for your precious help. but unfortunatly i need this format which i have added into my edited question.

Comment: if you can post screenshot of your table structure also, then it will be easier to reply.

Comment: i have added the screenshot of my programme table in my sedited question.

Comment: which column do you use as 'programme' ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45113/discussion-between-monty-and-bluebird)

Answer (score 1):

The query you want is:

```
SELECT campus1
       ,course1
       ,examdate
       ,count(*) AS count
FROM programme
WHERE examdate IN ('12-04-2014','07-06-2014')
GROUP BY campus1,course1,examdate
```

You may want to expand the `WHERE` clause if you don't want to include all campuses and courses.

Comment: thanks dear but unfortunatly i need this format which i have added into my edited question.

Answer (score -1):

here different solutions for ur problem

1. in the main page use combo and selecting campus, list details of that campus below that

combo using a ajax page

combo posting page  you just receive the value of that combo means compus name and add to
 ur sql directly.

If we use switch we want to enter a input to switch.  depending on this input we can

change the output in each case.